# CoreData with NSFetchResultController :Invalid update with with a property in fetchObjects

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a serious problem reported by Xcode :

**1. I have a NSFetchResultsController**

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Choice", inManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext())
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 10

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: false)
    let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

    //NSPredicate
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "decision.id = %@", decision.id!)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext(), sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

    do{
        try _fetchedResultsController?.performFetch()
    }catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController!
}
```

**2. And I have a button do add action:**

```
@IBAction func didTouchAddChoiceButton(sender: UIButton) {
    let choice = Choice.MR_createEntity() as! Choice
    choice.id = GDUtils.CMUUID()
    choice.decision = decision
    NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext().MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait()
}
```

**3. After adding this Entity. I have a controller to handle updating tableView like this**

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch(type){
    case .Insert:
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Top)

    case .Delete:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    case .Update:
        tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)

    case .Move:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Left)
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}
```

**4.But the problem happened : every time I try to change a property of an entity from fetchedObjects :**

```
let chosenChoice = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(currentIndextPath!) as! Choice
    chosenChoice.name = tableCell.choiceName.text
```

I got this message :

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

Can anyone help me to figure out what happened ?

Comment: You got this error because no rows were added or deleted  in managed objectContext of fetchResultsController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug in NSFetchedResultsController on iOS8, where FRC calls .Insert instead of .Update. I solved it the way, that I'm reloading the table completely, when .Insert is called on iOS8.

```
case .Insert:
    guard let newIndexPath = newIndexPath else { return }

    // iOS8 bug when FRC calls insert instead of Update
    if #available(iOS 9, *) {
        // insert item normally
    } else {
        // reload everything
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the managedOjectContext you assigned to NSFetchResultsController is same where you created new Choice NSManagedObject.

## ADDED

in "case .Update" code gives you cell of tableview. and you need to update tableView cell data for not getting that error. atleast change/(pretend change) sth in cell.

```
cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)
cell.choiceName.text = "empty"
```

Comment: I use MagicalRecord and it 's always assigned with MR_DefaultContext

Comment: see added section of above reply: I think this error is because you have changed nothing in table view while you update choice managedObject. It throws update notification to nsfetchresultcontroller but if you dont change cell, you might get this error.